# Is JHipster UAA enable to make user federation

Tags: single-sign-on, jhipster

I am studying JHipster architecture with some excitations. But now a question come up to me: is JHipster UAA server able to integrate to my already created LDAP directory server doing federation (Let's say Active Directory)?

Best Regards,

-Rod

Comment: You can use the OIDC support with Okta. Okta supports federation of AD and LDAP.

Comment: thank you Matt, i will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the documentation about LDAP [here](http://www.jhipster.tech/tips/016_tip_ldap_authentication.html) ?

Comment: That is for authentication. Federation is a little bit different. Thanks anyway.